# Rename columns with a loop in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I need to rename all the columns of a dataframe (pandas) with ~100 columns. I created a list with all the new names stored and i need a handy function to rename them. Many solutions online are dealing "manually" be stating the old column name, which is not possible with this size.

I tried a simple for loop like:

```
for i in range(0,96):
    df.columns[i] = new_cols_list[i]
```

That is the way i would do it in r, but it throws an error:

> "Index does not support mutable operations"

Comment: Just a tip, you could use `range(96)` to get the same result as `range(0, 96)`.

Comment: Looks like `df.columns = new_cols_list` ..?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is:

```
df.columns = new_cols_list
```

Use it only when you have to rename all columns. The new_col_list is the list containing the new names of columns with size equal to number of columns.

When you have to rename specific columns, then use 'rename' as shown in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the rename function:

```py
# df = some data frame
# new_col_list = new column names

# get the old columns names
old_columns = list(df)

# rename the columns inplate
df.rename(columns={old_columns[idx]: name for  (idx, name) in enumerate(new_col_list)}, inplace=True)
```

See also: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html